# Unquoting a String in Perl

Tags: perl

I have a subroutine in Perl sub findfiles , I have to pass a quoted value **"*/*"** as input parameter since it complains without quoting ,on the other hand in my subroutine I needed it to be unquoted (may be!)The problem is when I print the value to check ,I don't see any quote,or any thing but may be there are some special hidden character or something I don't know ? My codes work properly when I use */*directly but not when I pass it as as an  input parameter 
Do you have any idea?

```
sub findfiles {

    $dirname=$_[0];
    my @temp = grep {-f} <$dirname>;
    print @temp;       

}
&findfiles("*/*"); doesnot work

but 
   sub findfiles {

    $dirname=$_[0];
    my @temp = grep {-f} <*/*>;
    print @temp;       

}
```

does its job

Comment: Perhaps if you showed your code, it would be easier to understand what you mean. Do you mean to say that `mysub("*/*")` works, but `$test = "*/*"; mysub($test);` does not?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With your updated code, I can see where your error lies. While

```
my @temp = grep {-f} <*/*>;
```

Works as a `glob`

```
my @temp = grep {-f} <$dirname>;
```

Is interpreted as a [readline()](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readline.html) on the file handle `$dirname`.

If you want to avoid ambiguity you can use the function for [`glob`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html):

```
my @temp = grep -f, glob $dirname;
```

You might also be interested in using [File::Find](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File::Find), which finds files recursively.

**NOTE:** This problem could have been avoided if you had warnings turned on. As a rule of thumb, coding in perl without using

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

...is a very bad idea. These two pragmas will help you identify problems with your code.

Answer (score 2):

> The problem is when I print the value to check ,I don't see any quote

```
$test="*/*"
          ^string delimiter
       ^^^string
      ^string delimiter
```

When you print a string (be it from a string literal, a scalar or whatever) you print *the string*.

The delimiters don't get printed. They just tell perl where the edges of the data are.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know about [`File::Find`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3a%3aFind)?

```
use File::Find ();

File::Find::find( sub { say $File::Find::name if -f; } => $my_root );
```

Or what about [`File::Find::Rule`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3a%3aFind%3a%3aRule) (see [`file`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3a%3aFind%3a%3aRule#-X_tests))?

```
say foreach File::Find::Rule->file->in( $my_root );
```